# Normalizing a between 0 and 1 to a given minimum and maximum

Tags: c#, math

I'm dealing with the pitch of a joystick.

This pitch can vary between 0 (all down) and 1 (all up). 
A pitch of 0.5 would mean that the joystick is in its middle position.

I would like to find a formula that would "map" this pitch to a given minimum and maximum.

The formular would tell me

```
- that a joystick pitch value of 0 would correspond to a given minimum (let's say -20) 
- that a joystick pitch value of 1 would correspond to a given maximum (let's say 20)
- that a joystick pitch value of 0.5 would correspond to 0 (as it's in the middle of minimum and maximum
```

I have a black out, I don't find the formula to solve this riddle.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(max - min) * value + min` where `value` is in the range `[0,1]` should map it to the range `[min,max]`. In practice there may be some concerns, depending on the programming language† and values, e.g., if `min` and `max` are the minimum and maximum of a signed integer type, you cannot compute `max - min` without overflow in that same type. Using floating point types for all is probably safest.

† When I answered, the question was not tagged with any language, now it is tagged with C# which I am not particularly fluent in.

Comment: Works perfectly fine without any overhead, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

That's pretty simple, just take the proportion of the distance between `max` and `min` and add `min`:

```
public double Range(double val, double min, double max)
        =>  min + val * (max - min);
```

Example usage:

```
Range(0.0, -20, 20)
Range(0.5, -20, 20)
Range(1.0, -20, 20)
```

Output

```
-20
0
20
```

Answer (score 0):

This is normally known as the "map range" equation/function. Many graphics libraries come with this as a standard part of the library because of how commonly it's used.

Rosetta Code has implementations in every major language.

[The implementation and example for C#](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Map_range#C.23) is:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class MapRange
{
    public static void Main() {
        foreach (int i in Enumerable.Range(0, 11))
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} maps to {Map(0, 10, -1, 0, i)}");
    }

    static double Map(double a1, double a2, double b1, double b2, double s) => b1 + (s - a1) * (b2 - b1) / (a2 - a1);
}
```